# Problems with URL Encoded Characters that don't get rewrited

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have made some rules like a redirect Match to point old urls to new locations dynamically,
But any time i fall up with URL Encoded Characters inside any URL the redirect wasn't working at all.
Here is an example of those urls:

```
www.example.com/ebc-drama-yebet-sira/yebet-sira-%E1%8B%A8%E1%89%A4%E1%89%B5-%E1%88%B5%E1%88%AB-drama-part-1-video_80c33bc56.html
```

So i need to remove characters like :
**%E1%8B%A8%E1%89%A4%E1%89%B5-%E1%88%B5%E1%88%AB**
Those characters above are equal to this Amharic word:**የቤት-ስራ** 
What i need is a rule that removes non alpha -numerical characters from urls but keeping all special characters like "-" "_" etc just URL Encoded Characters.
 
I have tried :

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)>$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and :

```
RewriteRule (.*)[^a-zA-Z0-9](.*) $1$2 [N]
```

Htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^browse.html$ category.php
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos.html$ category.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-videos-([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ category.php?cat=$1&page=$2&sortby=$3
RewriteRule ^videos.flv(.*)$ videos.php$1
RewriteRule ^videos.mp4(.*)$ videos.php$1
RewriteRule ^register.html$ register.php
RewriteRule ^contact_us.html$ contact_us.php
RewriteRule ^edit_profile.html$ edit_profile.php
RewriteRule ^suggest.html$ suggest.php
RewriteRule ^upload.html$ upload.php
RewriteRule ^upload_avatar.html$ upload_avatar.php
RewriteRule ^suggest.html$ suggest.php
RewriteRule ^favorites.html(.*)$ favorites.php$1
RewriteRule ^login.html(.*)$ login.php$1
RewriteRule ^newvideos.html(.*)$ newvideos.php$1
RewriteRule ^topvideos.html(.*)$ topvideos.php$1
RewriteRule ^profile.html(.*)$ profile.php$1
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ user.php?u=$1&view=$2
RewriteRule ^memberlist.html(.*)$ memberlist.php$1
RewriteRule ^playlists.html(.*)$ playlists.php$1
RewriteRule ^index-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^browse-(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?c=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/tag/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ article.php?tag=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/tag/([^/]+)(/)?$ article.php?tag=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^popular-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?show=popular&page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([0-9]+).html$ article_read.php?a=$2
RewriteRule ^articles(\/|.html)?$ article.php
RewriteRule ^article(\/|.html)?$ article.php
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.html$ page.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^playlist/(.*)/([^/]+)(/)?$ watch.php?playlist=$1&vid=$2
RewriteRule ^playlist/(.*)$ playlists.php?playlist=$1
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/$ tag.php?t=$1&page=1
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)(/)?$ tag.php?t=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^embed/([^/]+)$ embed.php?vid=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ watch.php?vid=$2
RewriteRule ^fpembed-(.*).swf$ fpembed.php?vid=$1
RewriteRule ^uploads/thumbs/(.*)-social.(jpg|gif|png)$ social-thumb.php?vid=$1
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[\w-]+/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all css/js/images from rewrite rules below
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|articles?|user|tags|embed|playlist|uploads)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)[^\w/.-]+(.*\.html)$ $1$2 [DPI,N,E=SP:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:SP} =1
RewriteRule ^[\w.-]*$ /$0 [L,R=302,NE]

# comment out RedirectMatch 301 rule

# remaining RewriteRule appear here
```

This will redirect `/ebc-drama-yebet-sira/yebet-sira-%E1%8B%A8%E1%89%A4%E1%89%B5-%E1%88%B5%E1%88%AB-drama-part-1-video_80c33bc56.html` to `/ebc-drama-yebet-sirayebet-sira---drama-part-1-video_80c33bc56.html` by removing all special characters.

Comment: Sorry for delay @anubhava , actually this code has caused css to crash or website to load like infinitely.. I have to notice that am using another rule you gave me which is:`RedirectMatch 301 ^/[\w-]+/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1`  Also this old rule have made another issue that making the other htaccess files in subdirectories ponting to other domains not working(removing it will fix that but it's working correctly in main domain and the rule is important)

Comment: It's done.please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Comment out `RedirectMatch 301` rule and place my given rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: i did what you said bro , i think there is little issue that affects other directories in htaccess specially the articles related rules please take a look at the htaccess to see what this new rules can affect and how to fix it. thanks a lot again for your great work man it's very appreciated.

Comment: that way i see now even admin area cannot be loaded big mess bro!!

Comment: We need to ignore htaccess rules for admin directory and /articles (which is not   a physical subfolder )...

Comment: After this update all the articles are not working and returns errordocs 404 ...Actually i used `RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]` and it worked but only for admin subdirectory, the /articles  is virtual subdirectory don't know how to do it ...

Comment: It worked better now but still `/articles/popular-1.html` related to this  `RewriteRule ^popular-([0-9]+).html$ article.php?show=popular&page=$1` and `/pages/page_name.html` not working also

Comment: Also i have i question bro; how can i redirect `website.com/musicvideo.php?vid=VID` to  `website.com/watch.php?vid=VID` because the file musicvideo.php is replaced with  watch.php.

Comment: Great job man ! still just the /pages/page_name.html not working. and tell me for the other question if i have to include it in a new question or not.

Comment: For other problem use: `RewriteRule ^musicvideo\.php$ watch.php [L]`

Comment: Thanks a lot , Great Job Man!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-_./]
```

you can test your rule here
http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: if i add % then the url will keep % chars on it and will never redirect. http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: You are right ... I edited my answer above .. this will remove all % but keep the - and _ and also /

Comment: Internal Server Error